# column "statement_date" is of type date but expression is of type integer

Tags: postgresql

Consider the following query:

```
INSERT INTO     statement_line_items
SELECT      count(*)::integer as clicks, sum(amount_cents)::integer as amount_cents, imps.user_id, imps.created_at::date as statement_date
FROM        impression_events imps
INNER JOIN  transactions t ON t.event_id = imps.id
  AND       t.event_type = 'ImpressionEvent'
  AND       amount_cents >= 0
WHERE       imps.created_at >= (now() - interval '8 days')::date
  AND       imps.created_at < (now() - interval '7 day')::date
  AND       imps.clicked = true
GROUP BY    imps.user_id, imps.created_at::date;
```

This is returning:

```
ERROR:  column "statement_date" is of type date but expression is of type integer
LINE 2: ...icks, sum(amount_cents)::integer as amount_cents, imps.user_...
                                                             ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

********** Error **********

ERROR: column "statement_date" is of type date but expression is of type integer
SQL state: 42804
Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
Character: 117
```

My table structure for statement_line_items is:

```
"id";              "integer"
"user_id";         "integer"
"statement_date";  "date"
"description";     "character varying(255)"
"clicks";          "integer"
"amount_cents";    "integer"
"created_at";      "timestamp without time zone"
"updated_at";      "timestamp without time zone"
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You are putting the `imps.userid` in your `statement_date` column. That has to fail.

```
count(*)::integer as clicks                   goes into id
sum(amount_cents)::integer as amount_cents    goes into userid
imps.user_id                                  goes into statement_date
```

To specify the order you are inserting you can do this:

```
INSERT INTO statement_line_items (col1, col2, ...)
SELECT data_for_col1, data_for_col2, ...
```

Comment: Ah, I was under the impression that it inserted into the same named column.  That explains it.

Comment: For me insert statement which worked was: `INSERT INTO statement_line_items (col1, col2, ...)
select data_for_col1, data_for_col2, ... from xyz`. I am using Amazon Redshift.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this kind of problem check if your date is in the apostrophe.